# VB.net Loading Screen for every call to mySQL

Tags: vb.net

I made a loading screen that is not actually a loading screen. Its like showing a picturebox that has a "Loading" on it.

I was wondering if there is another way. Because my work like kinda sucks.

When I got a query I do this

```
Loading.show()
Panel_Main.Enable = False
```

After the query, success or not

```
Loading.hide()
Panel_Main.Enable = True
```

Loading and Panel_Main has the same parent.

What is the best way to put a loading screen to prevent the user to click another button and request another query.

EDIT:
I also made a showdialog() to open a modal form. The problem now is how to close that modal form after the query returns success or not?

I used this when I got a query

```
Dim form2 as New Form2
form2.showdialog() 'this opens the new modal form
```

And this after the query returns

```
form2.close()
```

This didnt work.

I also made the public sub in the Form2

```
Public sub closeMe()
    Me.close()
End sub
```

Then call this in form1

```
form2.closeMe()
```

Comment: The obvious choice is a modal dialogue, i.e. a form displayed by calling its `ShowDialog` method.  Just not that the form would have to close itself though, because `ShowDialog` will block until the form closes, so the caller cannot close the dialogue.

Comment: I already made that. showdialog() to open a new modal form, but problem is that how can I close that dialogue after the query is complete?

Comment: Why do you need a loading screen at all?  How slow is it?  Or, why not spend all this time working to speed it up rather than distract the user from how poorly it performs.

Comment: we are in a country that has slow internet connection. we have a remote database located somewhere i dont know where(godaddy). We need the loading screen to prevent the user to send another query if the existing query is still under way. We just want to learn, not to be criticized. Thank you.

Comment: Are you initiating this query on a `Button` click?  Can't you simply disable the `Button` until it's OK to initiate another query?  Anyway, I'll post an answer that shows how you can use a dialogue.

Comment: I made that already. But disabling all the controls inside a panel, Panel_Main.Enable = False and it actually working. I was wondering if there are other way in doing it. My further searching land me to BackgroundWokrger.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can display a modal dialogue while a method is executed in the calling form.  The trick is to get the dialogue to invoke the method so that it also knows when that method completes so that it can close itself.

Dialogue:

```
'The method to execute while the dialogue is displayed.
Private action As [Delegate]

'The arguments to the method to be executed.
Private args As Object()

'The result of the executed method, if there is one, can be retrieved from here.
Public Property Result As Object

Public Sub New(action As [Delegate], ParamArray args As Object())
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.action = action
    Me.args = args
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    'Make sure that the dialogue is displayed fully.
    Refresh()

    'Execute the method once the dialogue is displayed.
    Result = action.DynamicInvoke(args)

    'Close the dialogue when the method completes.
    Close()
End Sub
```

When the dialogue is created, it takes a delegate, i.e. a reference to a method, and a list of arguments for that method.  When the dialogue is displayed, it invokes that delegate, thereby executing the method.  When the method completes, it makes the result available via a public property and then closes.

Caller:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using dialogue As New Form2(New Func(Of Integer, String)(AddressOf GenerateRandomText), 10)
        dialogue.ShowDialog()

        Dim result = CStr(dialogue.Result)

        MessageBox.Show(result)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GenerateRandomText(length As Integer) As String
    Const chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    Dim rng As New Random
    Dim result = String.Empty

    For i = 1 To length
        result &= chars(rng.Next(chars.Length))

        'Simulate a long-running task.
        Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

In the example, the caller includes a method that generates a `String` of random lower-case letters.  It displays a dialogue and instructs that dialogue to invoke that method to create a `String` of 10 characters.  Once the dialogue closes, the `String` produced is retrieved from the dialogue and displayed.

Note that I have added the `Thread.Sleep` call just to make things take a bit longer so the dialogue doesn't disappear as soon as it appears.  Note also that the `Refresh` call is required in the dialogue because the long-running method is executed on the UI thread, which will otherwise prevent the dialogue painting correctly.  To do this all properly, the method really should be invoked on a secondary thread, but that does complicate things somewhat.

EDIT:

If you add a `BackgroundWorker` to the dialogue form then you can execute the method on a secondary thread.  Just be sure that the method you're executing doesn't access the UI or you may have cross-thread issues.

Dialogue:

```
'The method to execute while the dialogue is displayed.
Private action As [Delegate]

'The arguments to the method to be executed.
Private args As Object()

'The result of the executed method, if there is one, can be retrieved from here.
Public Property Result As Object

Public Sub New(action As [Delegate], ParamArray args As Object())
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.action = action
    Me.args = args
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'Execute the method on a background thread.
    Result = action.DynamicInvoke(args)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    'Close the dialogue when the method completes.
    Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is VB.net right? This is new to me. Ill try to use this. Thanks. I will posts my progress later.

Comment: It is indeed VB.NET. There may be a few new concepts in there.

Comment: Hi, this is hard for me LOL, cant understand much but im trying to. Anywayss, I have search about BackGroundWorker, do you have any idea how to use this for my project?

Comment: I've added another code example that includes a `BackgroundWorker`.